# Magic Mouse disconnects macOS Mojave (MacBook Pro 2018)

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth, mouse

I bought a new 2018 MacBook Pro with Touch Bar. I am experiencing Bluetooth issues such as my Magic Mouse disconnecting randomly and lagging. These are the steps I have taken (not in the order as listed here) though I am still experiencing the dropouts. Any other suggestions?

- Removed Bluetooth devices from existing connections.
- [Turn off and on Bluetooth and Wifi](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/154837/magic-mouse-can-never-reconnect-on-yosemite).
- [Remove `Bluetooth PAN` from network interface](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/154837/magic-mouse-can-never-reconnect-on-yosemite).
- [Have fresh batteries](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15709/magic-mouse-is-frequently-losing-its-connection-to-macbook-pro).
- [Remove the cover from the mouse](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15709/magic-mouse-is-frequently-losing-its-connection-to-macbook-pro).
- [Put a piece of paper between the batteries and the cover](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15709/magic-mouse-is-frequently-losing-its-connection-to-macbook-pro).
- Clean connectors from mouse.
- [Debug Bluetooth](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8225334).
- Remove and reconnect Bluetooth devices.
- [Disable Handoff](https://mjtsai.com/blog/2018/08/15/continued-mac-bluetooth-problems/).
- [Reset NVRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063).
- [Restarted in safe mode to isolate issues with your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262).
- [A combination of disconnecting, resetting NVRAM, safe mode, and pairing](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8330226).
- Unplugged USB-C hub to avoid interference.
- [Checked for metal objects and 2.4GHz interference](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204621#5).
- Renamed my Bluetooth devices.
- [Removed com.apple.Bluetooth.plist](https://www.lifewire.com/fix-os-x-bluetooth-wireless-problems-2259967) (whenever the Bluetooth is about to cut out a copy of `com.apple.Bluetooth.plist` is created, not sure if this means something).

[Edit: I have had my Bluetooth antenna in my MacBook replaced and it is somewhat better, though, still not fully solved]

Comment: This is excellent debugging. Only one thing I see missing: Have you tried a different mouse? Do you experience this with any other Bluetooth devices?

Comment: Have the same issue. Have also reset the bluetooth connections and devices (Shift+Option+Bluetooth -> Debug -> Reset Bluetooth Modules & Factory Reset Connected Devices). The mouse worked and works perfectly on my prior MacBook Pro 2013 (High Sierra) but lags and disconnects/reconnects frequently (5-10 minutes) while not being used (while I'm typing).

Comment: I've just brought home a Magic Mouse 2 from work and I am testing it right now. Good suggestion. I will let you know how it goes!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I forgot this one to add to the list in my original post but I have tried it as well and it didn't help the problem.

Comment: @UnassumingGuy The Magic Mouse 2 doesn't cut out as frequently at all, very big improvement, so maybe the compatibility of the Magic Mouse 1 with the new Macbook 2018 isn't that good. The Magic Mouse 1 works still fine with the older Macbook.

Comment: I have been having the same problems with my 2018 MacBook Pro- I completed all the same steps as the OP, Apple could not solve the problem so they gave me a new MBP, but the same problem has persisted. I have also tried multiple Magic Mouses, generation 1, generation 2 and other brands- all have the same issue. I have also read that turning off "Handoff" could correct the problem, but that has not worked for me yet.

Comment: So did any of this solve the issue?

Comment: @MateiSuica I am still experiencing the issue and now my keyboard cuts out frequently too :(

Comment: I've managed to get rid of the problems after an operating system reinstall. My initial OS was restored from a Backup of my previous laptop. Seems like it did not like that. Now it is all good

Comment: @MateiSuica I also had my copy restored from a previous laptop from a backup. I have troubleshooted with Apple on the phone and they advised me to reinstall Mojave. I have done that last night and I have only had a couple of cutouts (maybe random) so it may have solved the problem too.

Answer (score 3):

Updating Xcode has limited the disconnects from the keyboard and Magic Mouse (still not perfect but much better).

To update Xcode, open your Terminal and enter `xcode-select --install`. 
You may have to delete the old version of Xcode before installing the latest Xcode. Make sure to also install the command line developer tools.

Comment: On my Macbook Pro 2019 I had suddenly the same behaviour with a Dell Bluetooth mouse. So I bought a Magic Mouse 2 but the disconnects persisted. I spent days in trying all of the Voodoo like described in this question

Finally I sent the Macbook back to Apple and they fixed it. They told me that they just updatet the firmware of the wlan module.